# Using Generic type to have a general method

Tags: java

I want to have a method in Java with given column(s( of an array it extracts these columns from main column.

I wrote the following code:

```
public static String[][] extractCol(String[][] matrix, int[] col){


     String [][] output = new String [matrix.length][col.length];
     int con=0;  
     for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
         con=-1;
         for (int j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
             con++;
             output[i][con]=matrix[i][col[j]];   
         }


    }
        return output;   
    }
```

However, if the input data is int data , it doesn't work, so I have to write another method to accept int data to do exactly same thing. Moreover, if I want to have int output again I should have another method to generate same thing but with string format.

So to have a function for all different inputs and outputs type needs, I should write and call 4 different methods. Is there any way in JAVA to merge all of them and have one method which accept generic input and generate a generic output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to define generic inputs and outputs (with a but)...

```
public static <T> T[][] extractCol(Class<T> componentType, T[][] matrix, int[] col) {
  T[][] output = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(componentType, matrix.length, col.length);
  ...
}
```

But this will only work with object input and output types like `Integer` but will not work with primitive types as such `int` (which may make this solution useless in for your use case), because this uses generics, and generics in Java are for objects only.

If you want to support primitive types, you'll have to define separate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public static Object[][] extractCol(Object[][] matrix, int[] col){
    Object[][] output = new Object[matrix.length][col.length];
    int con=0;  
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        con=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            output[i][con]=matrix[i][col[j]];   
            con++;
        }    
    }
    return output;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Object[][] extractCol(final Object[][] matrix, final int[] col){
    final Object [][] output = new Object [matrix.length][col.length];
     int con=0;  
     for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
         con=-1;
         for (final int element : col) {
             con++;
             output[i][con]=matrix[i][element];   
         }
    }
    return output;   
}
```

Cannot use generic for creating array...

Or you can give the output in method args.

```
public static <T>void extractCol(final T[][] matrix, final int[] col, final T[][] output){
     int con=0;  
     for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
         con=-1;
         for (final int element : col) {
             con++;
             output[i][con]=matrix[i][element];   
         }
    }
}
```